# Interpolation problem

Tags: graphing-functions, interpolation

I have the equation $f(x)=148x^4 + 3x^3 + 251x^2 + 56x + 157$.

This equation gives us the points below.

$(0,157),(1,101), (2,67), (3,4), (4,72)$

I want to interpolate this points in a $4$ degree polynomial, to get the equation $f(x)$ above.

However, when I try to make the interpolation using matrices, with Octave, i get a different equation $((157 -136, 75 x + 133,2083 x^2 - 61, 25 x^3 +8, 7917x^4))$. Does anyone knows what is happening, and how I can fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want the 4-degree interpolant?

Comment: yes, that is the one i want ...

Comment: For those of us not familiar with Octave, can you explain what $((157 -136,75x + 133, 2083x^2 -61, 25x^3 +8,7917x^4))$ is supposed to be?

Comment: @GeorgeV.Williams That is his proposed 4-degree polynomial interpolant given those 5 points, (I believe this is the polynomial is program is spitting back @ him).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Octave is like matlab. Basically, what octave and matlab do, is to solve matrices. the f(x) i mention above, i just an equation

Comment: Basically, from the equation, i got the points. Now i'm trying to do the opposite. From the points i want the equation

Comment: @Andreas Does your code work for other examples?

Comment: What i'm trying to do, is descibed here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing

Comment: @Andreas ah you're trying to construct the lagrange basis polynomials from points ? Ok.

Comment: @Rustyn Yes, thank you very much :))))

Answer (score 1):

Shamir's secret sharing scheme uses finite field arithmetic instead of integer arithmetic, and in your example, it seems that the field $\mathbb{Z}_{257}$ was used. For example, modulo $257$ we indeed have $f(1) = 615 \equiv 101 \mod 257$, but your polynomial does not satisfy $f(1) = 101$ over the reals. So if you try to interpolate this polynomial over the reals, you will get a different function.

Note that those five points uniquely determine a degree-4 polynomial over the reals, which is the one you mention, but it is not the function $f$ you are looking for.

Comment: yes, this was the field that was used! :) Thank you :) But do you know what steps i should follow in order to find the function i am looking for? In addition do you know how to interpolate this points using matlab in the field Z*257? I don't know very match, and i really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Andreas: See [this page](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/interpolate.html), Example 4. It seems that you want something like `F := Dom::IntegerMod(257): P := interpolate([XList, YList], values, [X, Y], F)`.

Comment: Thank you. i will study the page. Do you also know how to do this, by hand? i mean, what steps i should follow in order to find out the function I am looking for without using a computer?

Comment: to do by hand see this link: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_interpolant), @Andreas

Comment: You basically want to solve $Ax \equiv b \mod 257$, where $$A = \left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 16 & 8 & 4 & 2 & 1 \\ 81 & 27 & 9 & 3 & 1 \\ 256 & 64 & 16 & 4 & 1\end{matrix}\right), \quad x = \left(\begin{matrix} a_4 \\ a_3 \\ a_2 \\ a_1 \\ a_0 \end{matrix}\right), \quad b = \left(\begin{matrix} 157 \\ 101 \\ 67 \\ 4 \\ 72 \end{matrix}\right).$$ The solution will be $(a_4, a_3, a_2, a_1, a_0) = (148, 3, 251, 56, 157)$.

Comment: @TMM yes, indeed, but how i can solve matrices with mod

Comment: @Andreas: You can solve $Ax \equiv b$ as you would do it over the integers, e.g., with Gaussian elimination. But instead of "dividing" rows by $x$, you have to multiply them with $x^{-1}$, the inverse of $x$ in the finite field.